# How to toast after pressing a big view notification button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, toast, android-toast

So I am brand new to android development and I was wondering if there was a way to get a toast to popup after pressing a button in a big view notification. I am using intents and addActions to add the buttons to the notification but they don't have any functionality.

The buttons say confirm and cancel. So for now I want a toast to pop that says "Status Confirmed" after pressing confirm and then the notification will disappear.

Any advice is welcome. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
Intent confirmIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        confirmIntent.setAction(""); // ToDo; Add functionality to the confirm button
        PendingIntent piConfirm = PendingIntent.getService(context,0, confirmIntent, 0);

        Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        cancelIntent.setAction(""); // ToDo: Add functionality to the cancel button
        PendingIntent piCancel = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, cancelIntent, 0);

        // Changed Notification.Builder to NotificationCompat.Builder for
        // Big View Style notification compatibility
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setLights(0xffffffff, 500, 100)
                .setTicker(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(alertString)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(alertString))
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel, getString(R.string.cancel), piCancel)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_ok, getString(R.string.confirm), piConfirm);
```

This is what I have right now. As you can see there is no button object and therfore cannot use a setOnClickListener or at least not that I know of. I want it so the confirmIntent launches a toast. The UI shows two buttons under the notification which say "confirm" and "cancel" which are handled by the confirmIntent and cancelIntent.

Currently, they don't do anything and I'm having trouble conceptualizing how to add a toast to the buttons when they aren't technically buttons.

Also, this is inside a Service class and not an activity or fragment.

Comment: Show your code and point to what in the code should trigger the toast.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: I've added some code

Comment: As you said,  "The buttons say confirm and cancel.". Now , the pendingintent used inside the line  'addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_ok, getString(R.string.confirm), piConfirm);' -- piConfirm is fired while you tap on "confirm". this pendingintent start a service. So show the toast from that service.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       Toast.makeText(context, "Status Confirmed", TOAST.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
});
```

Comment: Here's the thing. The buttons aren't button types so I can't use setOnClickListener unless you know how to change an .setAction and .addAction to a button.

Comment: Also I'm using this as more or less of a template https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html

Answer (score 0):

5 years later, I bumped into this & the suggested solution didn't work for me.

What worked was to create a custom [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) then display the toast from there.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,YourBroadcast.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,0, intent, 0);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, YOUR_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
            ...
            .addAction(R.drawable.my_icon, context.getString(R.string.click_me), pendingIntent)
            .build();
```

**In your receiver**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"I made it!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Don't forget to register your receiver in the Manifest.